# Are subset of an recursively enumerable set necessary recursive enumerable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, recursion

So I wanted to ask

Are subset of an r.e set necessary r.e. ?

I feel that the answer is no, but I cant come up with an easy counter-example.
But I cant come up with a simple proof for the contrary either.

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is r.e.

Comment: Also, there are countably many partial recursive functions, so at most countably many r.e. sets.